# The result of a shell_exec in function launched in a foreach is not displayed

Tags: php, linux, snmp

I'm trying to make a "snmpget" on an IP table and display it using a foreach. I'm already doing a ping. On my web page, only the ping result is displayed. No sign of the snmp result.

The command in shell_exec() work when I write it in a Linux shell and return "6.0.0." for each IP (yes, with the "").

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
            ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); //debug

            function pingAddress($ip) {
                 $pingresult = exec("ping -c 1 $ip", $outcome, $status);
                    if (0 == $status) {
                        $status = "reachable";
                    } else {
                        $status = "unreachable!";
                    }
                    echo "<p>IP state: <strong>$ip</strong> is".$status."</p>";
            }

            function snmp($ip) {
                 $snmpresult = shell_exec('snmpget -v 2c -c public $ip 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0 | awk \'{print $4}\''); //changed the OID just for confidentiality
                 echo $snmpresult;
            }

            $arr = array('192.168.1.11', '192.168.1.12', '192.168.1.2');
            foreach ($arr as &$value) {
                 pingAddress($value);
                 snmp($value);
            }

            unset($value);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The actual result on my web page is this:

```
IP state: 192.168.1.11 is reachable
IP state: 192.168.1.12 is reachable
IP state: 192.168.1.2 is reachable
```

And I don't see the snmp() result. Any idea? I'm far from being a real PHP developer so if you have any other recommendations, don't hesitate. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to use php function `snmpget()` http://php.net/manual/de/function.snmpget.php

Comment: Maybe you're getting an error. Try getting the error output as well: `$snmpresult = shell_exec('snmpget -v 2c -c public $ip 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0 | awk \'{print $4}\' 2>&1');`

Comment: @Barmar I have typed the command in a Linux shell, outside of this program and it works correctly. However, I tried to add the "2>&1" and nothing changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used single quotes to build the command string, [so `$ip` is not interpolated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single).

Furthermore, you did not provide yourself with any means to see error messages coming out of the `snmpget` command, otherwise this might have been more obvious.

A quick fix would be something like:

```
function snmp($ip)
{
    $oid = "1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.0";
    $cmd = "snmpget -v 2c -c public $ip $oid | awk '{print \$4}'";
    $snmpresult = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $snmpresult;
}
```

I've split the string into variables so we can read it all better, plus now you can print `$cmd` for debugging (which also would have revealed your bug).

And I recommend returning the result rather than `echo`ing it directly, so that the calling scope can do something else with it if it likes.

For better diagnostics, and just better code overall, consider switching to the built-in [`snmpget`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php) function; direct shell commands are almost always a hack.

You should also bear in mind that, for security reasons, a webserver is often run in a constrained context, preventing certain operations from being performed. If `snmpget` doesn't work at all, you could look to see whether something like SELinux is disallowing it.

Comment: If the single quotes are the problem, why the pingAddress() function works?

How can I output the error messages, then?

Comment: @a_v_e_ Because you used double quotes in the `pingAddress()` function.

Comment: I misread your first answer, my bad. Thank you for the details you have just provided. I will take a closer look at the native SNMP function in PHP. Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: As for getting an error message, it would be a bit messy, which is one of the reasons that avoiding shell commands is preferred. That being said, `snmpget` only returns `FALSE` on failure which isn't terribly helpful, though it's better than nothing, and you can at least be better assured about what parameters you're passing in because they won't be munged into a big string. Overall, I can't say I've seen SNMP used from PHP very often; seems like a bit of an edge case.